# Template for Windows Phone Apps Development in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sdk, windows-phone, visual-studio-templates

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed but it does not give option to develop windows phone apps. Is there any template that I can download for this or any other solution so that i can carry out win apps development with my current Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to download and install this:

- [**Windows Phone SDK**](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)

You can choose here which version you want to install. The SDK provides an emulator and several other tools for developing Windows Phone apps as well as templates for Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.